# How can I correctly reference a source directly in an article under Harvard-style rules for publications?

Tags: style-manuals

I am trying to reference a source directly in an article that I am writing using “Harvard-style” referencing. The source I am using is an article published on a radio station’s “news articles” page. As the author, they have only written “KHTS Articles”.

Would this be a correct way to start a paragraph while referencing the source without any author by using only the radio station’s name?

> In their article, KHTS (2020) writes how...

Comment: Have you considered simply putting the URL in a footnote? Then, in the body of the text, you can just write "A recent article from a local radio station notes that...", with the footnote marker at the end of the sentence. I think it's a bit jarring to see informal sources in a bibliography, and the footnote URL solution is something I have often seen (especially when Wikipedia is the source), and which I feel is a sufficiently elegant solution.

Comment: What does the on-line reference say about this?